# Python Looping through CSV files and their columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

so I've seen this done is other questions asked here but I'm still a little confused. I've been learning python3 for the last few days and figured I'd start working on a project to really get my hands dirty. I need to loop through a certain amount of CSV files and make edits to those files. I'm having trouble with going to a specific column and also for loops in python in general. I'm used to the convention (int i = 0; i < expression; i++), but in python it's a little different. Here's my code so far and I'll explain where my issue is.

```
import os
import csv

pathName = os.getcwd()

numFiles = []
fileNames = os.listdir(pathName)
for fileNames in fileNames:
    if fileNames.endswith(".csv"):
        numFiles.append(fileNames)

for i in numFiles:
    file = open(os.path.join(pathName, i), "rU")
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    for column in reader:
        print(column[4])
```

My issue falls on this line:

```
for column in reader:
        print(column[4])
```

So in the Docs it says column is the variable and reader is what I'm looping through. But when I write 4 I get this error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What does this mean? If I write 0 instead of 4 it prints out all of the values in column 0 cell 0 of each CSV file. I basically need it to go through the first row of each CSV file and find a specific value and then go through that entire column. Thanks in advance!

Comment: it means that somewhere in one of your files, there isn't any 5th column.

Comment: `for column in reader`? Isn't it `for row in reader`? And don't forget to use `with` to ensure that the file is closed after the process: `with open(os.path.join(pathName, i), "rU") as file:`

Comment: Awesome, thanks for all the answers! @azalea Why 5? I'm trying to understand how that for loop works.

Comment: A common cause of this is that you have an empty line somewhere in your file. e.g. the first or last line. You could add something like `if len(row) == 4:`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `for aFileName in fileNames:` instead of `for fileNames in fileNames:`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It could be that you don't have 5 columns in your .csv file.

Python is base0 which means it starts counting at 0 so the first column would be column[0], the second would be column[1].

Also you may want to change your

```
for column in reader:
```

to

```
for row in reader:
```

because reader iterates through the rows, not the columns.

This code loops through each row and then each column in that row allowing you to view the contents of each cell.

```
for i in numFiles:
    file = open(os.path.join(pathName, i), "rU")
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        for column in row:
            print(column)
            if column=="SPECIFIC VALUE":
                #do stuff
```

Comment: Yeah, I need to read the docs more. Now I understand what's going on and thank you! I really liked both yours and Doron Cohen's answer.

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to Python! I suggest you to print some debugging messages.

You could add this to you printing loop:

```
for row in reader:
    try:
        print(row[4])
    except IndexError as ex:
        print("ERROR: %s in file %s doesn't contain 5 colums" % (row, i))
```

This will print bad lines (as lists because this is how they are represented in `CSVReader`) so you could fix the CSV files.

Some notes:

1. It is common to use `snake_case` in Python and not `camelCase`
2. Name your variables appropriately (`csv_filename` instead of `i`, `row` instead of `column` etc.)
3. Use the `with` close to handle files ([read more](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/))

Enjoy!

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I completely forgot about debugging messages....how silly of me. Yeah, I'm so used to camelCase, but I'll switch to snake_case. Thank you! I really liked both yours and Philip556677's answer.