# How to loop through a .csv file in python

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, iterator, append

I am trying to loop through a .csv file so I can read each line, but I am receiving the following error:

`AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'iterrows'`

Here is my code so far:

```
def i_list(input_file):

    input_list = []
    file = open(input_file, 'r')
    for i, j in file.iterrows():
            num1 = j[1]
            num2 = j[2]
            input_list.append(num1)
            input_list.append(num2)

i_list('nums.csv')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Looping through CSV files and their columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947887/python-looping-through-csv-files-and-their-columns)

Comment: [Here are the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) for file i/o. You might be mixing up `read` or `readline` for `iterrows`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [csv library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

```py
import reader from csv

input_list=[]
f = reader(open(input_file))
header = next(f) # if there is a header
for num1, num2 in f:
    input_list.append(num1)
    input_list.append(num2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
for row in df.iterrows():
  # do something
```

If you don't want to use Pandas, try to read the file using: `file.readlines()`

```py
with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
  # do something
```