# Python: how do I convert all columns except one in a CSV to integers

Tags: python

I have CSV files with varying number of columns. The first column is always a string, the other columns are always integers.

The first column is always "name", but the other columns can have different names - so I cannot hardcode the key values for any column except for "name".

Ideally there would be some kind of syntax/function that would allow me to do `!"name" to int` and then I could put something together.

Here is what I have now, it does not do the conversion to int, it just builds a dictionary.

```
import csv

persons = []
    database_csv = sys.argv[1]
    with open(database_csv, "r") as database:
            read_csv = csv.DictReader(database)
            for row in read_csv:
                persons.append(row)
```

I have found solutions to convert all to int, key (for example "name") to int, but I could not find anything that would let me convert everything except "name" to int.

Please note that I am using a dictionary, not a list. Solutions for lists are not directly useful downstream. If no viable solution for selectively changing datatypes within a dictionary without resorting to pandas exist then I will need to reconsider the dictionary approach and figure out how to make the rest of the code work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Looping through CSV files and their columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947887/python-looping-through-csv-files-and-their-columns)

Comment: Following the suggested duplicate ([accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45948252/15032126)), use `for column in row[1:]:`. That should do the trick.

Comment: I cannot use pandas, as in it is not available nor deployable in the environment. But thank you.

Comment: OK, your suggestion and "suggested duplicate" dropped a good hint, but it is not a duplicate and it creates a different problem:

attempting `for column in row[1:];` gives me an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`

Could you expand on your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you heard about pandas. But you can used the following

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(database_csv)
persons = df.values.tolist()
```

Comment: I cannot use pandas, as in it is not available nor deployable in the environment. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps ,

```
import csv

persons = []
with open("database.csv", "r") as database:
    read_csv = csv.DictReader(database)
    for row in read_csv:
        # Type decl does nothing.
        row: dict
        print(row.keys())
        for key in row.keys():
            print(row[key])
```

Comment: I am trying to implement your suggestion, but  I will need to walk away from this problem for a while, or find a rubber ducky.

 `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Charlie'`

Comment: Casting strings to int with int() works for cases like "5"->5 not for "Pambos"->52131 .

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
import csv


with open(database_csv) as fp:
    csvreader = csv.reader(fp)
    headers = next(csvreader)
    name_idx = headers.index('name')
    rows = [row for row in csvreader]
    rows = [int(value) for value in row for row in rows if row.index(value) != name_idx]
```

Comment: This looks interesting. I will try it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

To convert every value in a dict, except that for one certain key, you could do

```
converted = {k: (v if k == 'name' else int(v)) for k, v in row.items()}
```

Let’s pick this apart:

- `{k: v for k, v in ... }` — This is a [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays), which lets us iterate over something and build a dict from the result. In this case, we expect the ... to be a sequence of pairs, which we pick apart into two variables with the `k, v` construct.
- `v if k=='name' else int(v)` — we use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) to decide, for each item, what to do with it — keep it as-is or call `int()`on it.
- `row.items())` — this gives us each element of the `row` dict as a (key, value) pair, which is what we said in the first point that we were expecting.

(If you have several keys that you wish to keep unchanged, you could do

```
excluded = set(['name', 'address', 'preferred_colour'])
```

and then use `if k in excluded_set` instead of `if k=='name'`)
)

Comment: Thank you! This works very well. Also thank you for the time you took to break down your suggestion. I still cannot upvote as I lack karma, but hopefully someone else can do that.